# htaccess rewrite query string for all pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this and what it does, it changes query string like you will see in example below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options Allow All
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ otherpage.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

So if I have link like:

http://example.com/folder/otherpage.php?id=123

This htaccess will let access that link from:

http://example.com/page/123

What I want to is to change a query string look for ANY (all) of my pages (without any folder) like:

http://example.com/mypage1.php?id=123

should be accessible through:

http://example.com/mypage1/page/123

And the same with mypage2.php, andpage3.php, etc.

Comment: yes, you can remove it, it doesn't but I am not about that. please see the answer below and the comments of it

Comment: didn't need that. found another solution to remove .php which works fine together with the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: it almost works, but it gives "500 Internal Server Error" because I use this one too. Without this, your code works perfectly: `RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` This makes pages accessible without .php and I need that. What should I do to make them both work together?